# Simplification of a solution of a recursive equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, closed-form, recursion

I have obtained the following solution to a recursive equation **$r(m,n)=\frac{ab^{n-1}c^{m-1}}{(2a-1)^{m+n}}\left[\frac{(2a)^n}{b^{n-1}}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2a-b)^i(1-b)^{m-i}\binom{m-1}{i-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-i+1}\binom{j+i-2}{i-1}(\frac{2a}{b})^{n-j-i+1}\right]$**, where **a, b, c** are combines of some parameters to the recursive equation **$r(m,n)=\frac{c}{2a-1}[r(m,n-1)+c\frac{2a-b}{2a-1} \sum_{j=1}^{m-1} \left((1-b)\frac{c}{2a-1}\right)^{m-j-1} r(j,n-1) ]$** and the initial condition **$r(m,0)=a\frac{c^{m-1}}{(2a-1)^m}$**. I need the above solution to be more compact. It would be better to get a simplified and a single term solution. I guess there may be a simple sum to the series involved there in.

Comment: Where did this equation come from?

Comment: @KentaS, This is the solution of a recursive equation. I am editing the question to include the equation too

Comment: *Mathematica* simply rewrites the double-sum using `Hypergeometric2F1` and `DifferenceRoot` (the latter of which I'd never seen before, but apparently represents a holonomic sequence determined by a particular linear difference equation). Not particularly helpful. :)

Comment: @Blue, yes `Mathematica` is not helpful though as the `DifferenceRoot` doesn't return a good answer at least to me.